# React JS event handler arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading about ["Lifting State Up"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in React JS documentation and there is something I am not very clear about. The codepen can be found here: https://codepen.io/valscion/pen/jBNjja?editors=0010

In the TemperatureInput component, the onTemperatureChange event handler calls the handleCelsiusChange, but the latter contains a parameter of temperature. How are we passing this parameter? There is no argument passed in the onTemperatureChange. What am I missing here?

Hope someone can help me understand this.

```
class TemperatureInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onTemperatureChange(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const temperature = this.props.temperature;
    const scale = this.props.scale;
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter temperature in {scaleNames[scale]}:</legend>
        <input value={temperature}
               onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCelsiusChange = this.handleCelsiusChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFahrenheitChange = this.handleFahrenheitChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {temperature: '', scale: 'c'};
  }

  handleCelsiusChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature});
  }

  handleFahrenheitChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'f', temperature});
  }

  render() {
    const scale = this.state.scale;
    const temperature = this.state.temperature;
    const celsius = scale === 'f' ? tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius) : temperature;
    const fahrenheit = scale === 'c' ? tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit) : temperature;

    return (
      <div>
        <TemperatureInput
          scale="c"
          temperature={celsius}
          onTemperatureChange={this.handleCelsiusChange} />
        <TemperatureInput
          scale="f"
          temperature={fahrenheit}
          onTemperatureChange={this.handleFahrenheitChange} />
        <BoilingVerdict
          celsius={parseFloat(celsius)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you share code of `TemperatureInput` component so that I can see what are you passing in `onTemperatureChange`.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the TemperatureInput component first. When its input element fires a change event, this is handled by `handleChange(e)` (declared within the TemperatureInput component). You'll notice that it then calls `this.props.onTemperatureChange` with the parameter `e.target.value` (this is the value attribute of the input element).

Where does `this.props.onTemperatureChange` come from? It's set by the parent component Calculator that instantiates it. Looking at the render method of the Calculator component, you'll notice that the `onTemperatureChange` prop for each TemperatureInput instance is set to `this.handle[Cel/Far]Change` (both methods declared within the Calculator component).

So when the TemperatureInput component calls `this.props.onTemperatureChange`, it is in fact calling the `handle[Cel/Far]Change` method of the Calculator component.

Answer (score 0):

Here to the TemperatureInput component you are passing the function (it acts like a pointer).

This is passed from Calculator to TemperatureInput component.

Now we see, our function handleCelsiusChange requires one argument, Therefore when we call onTemperatureChange function inside TemperatureInput component, we must be passing some variable there.

As you can see below code you are passing the parameter to the function call.

```
 handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onTemperatureChange(e.target.value);
  }
```

This where we are passing the argument to the function from TemperatureInput component

Answer (score 0):

> In the TemperatureInput component, the onTemperatureChange event handler calls the handleCelsiusChange...

This assumption is incorrect.
You are passing a reference to the function object `this.handleCelsiusChange` to the attribute `onTemperatureChange` in the `render` function.

This function object is then used by *calling it* in `TemperatureInput` class.

```
this.props.onTemperatureChange(e.target.value)
```

If it were to call the handleCelciusChange in the JSX, the `render` would look like:

```
    <TemperatureInput
      scale="c"
      temperature={celsius}
      onTemperatureChange={this.handleCelsiusChange(some_value)} />
```